# Data Transferring Problem from Client to Server in C++

Tags: c++, server, client

I have a client that sends array data to server with UDP datagrams. In order to be able to trace the data I sent I fill my array with numbers. For example; *in client code* I fill `buf[7] = 7;`  this index is to indicate the total number of fragments. I expect to see the same *in server* too.

However, my `buf` *in server* does not get those values. 
I have to use fixed sized char array *in server* I can not change it. (I perform long calculations with the data, I didn't put it since it is unrelated with the problem)

**I have to explain server structure:**

- I hold a queue. Queue contains 3 buffers. If I get data too fast and
  if `buf` is full and still its data on file, `buf2` should be used
  and so on. It is for optimization purpose.
- I use a thread, it writes current buffers data into a file on a
  parallel manner. I signal to thread so it knows when to start
  writing.

*I suspected thread*, when I comment it, receive function stucks.
*I suspected* type of arrays since I send char pointer array but receive fixed sized char array. (Again I have to use fixed size while receiving)

> All I want is to see the data correctly transferred. When I look at
>   server I want to see the same data at same indexes.
>
> Here is my simple client code

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cout << "Can't start Winsock! " << wsOk;
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; // AF_INET = IPv4 addresses
    server.sin_port = htons(...port no...); // Little to big endian conversion
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "...IP....", &server.sin_addr); // Convert from string to byte array

    SOCKET out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    int sendOk = 0;

    int *buf = new int[1450];

    //just fill it with ordered number to be able to trace from other side
    for (int i = 0; i < 1450; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = i;
    }

    buf[7] = 7; // this index represent TotalFragmentCount in UDP

    while (true) {

        for (int fragmentNumber = 1; fragmentNumber < 8; fragmentNumber++) {
            //I want to set this index to count fragment number when I look at server
            buf[9] = fragmentNumber;
            //I give it as char * array with reinterpret_cast, since sendto accepts pointer char array
            sendOk = sendto(out, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf), 1450, 0, (sockaddr*)& server, sizeof(server));
        }

    }

    if (sendOk == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "That didn't work! " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }

    closesocket(out);
    WSACleanup();

}
```

> Here is my server code

```
void writeToFile(char buf[], vector<uint16_t> &intData, ofstream &file) {


    while (true) {

        if (signaled == 1) {
            thread_mutex.lock();
            //writing...
            for (const auto& e : intData) {
                file << e << "\n";
            }
            buffers.pop(); // pops front which is written by this time
            buffers.push(buf);
            thread_mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}
// Main entry point into the server
void main()
{
    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        // Not ok! Get out quickly
        cout << "Can't start Winsock! " << wsOk;
        return;
    }

    // Create a socket, notice that it is a user datagram socket (UDP)
    SOCKET in = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    sockaddr_in serverHint;
    serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY; // Us any IP address available on the machine
    serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET; // Address format is IPv4
    serverHint.sin_port = htons(4660); // Convert from little to big endian

    // Try and bind the socket to the IP and port
    if (bind(in, (sockaddr*)&serverHint, sizeof(serverHint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Can't bind socket! " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in client; // Use to hold the client information (port / ip address)
    int clientLength = sizeof(client); // The size of the client information


    char buf[1550] = { 0 }; //message gets here
    char buf2[1550]= { 0 };
    char buf3[1550]= { 0 };

    // Control buffer traffic with queue
    buffers.push(buf);
    buffers.push(buf2);
    buffers.push(buf3);

    std::thread thread_write(writeToFile, std::ref(buffers.front()), std::ref( intData), std::ref(file)); //front returns first element of the queue

    bytesIn = recvfrom(in, buffers.front(), 1550, 0, (sockaddr*)& client, &clientLength);
    cout << "";
    while (ReceivedFrameCount != 100)
    {
            ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength); // Clear the client structure

            // Wait for message
            bytesIn = recvfrom(in, buffers.front(), 1550, 0, (sockaddr*)& client, &clientLength);

            if (bytesIn == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Error receiving from client " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                continue;
            }

            // Parse the byte array

            TotalFragmentCount = (uint16_t)(buf[6] << 8 | buf[7]);
            FrameFragmentNo = (uint16_t)(buf[8] << 8 | buf[9]);

            signaled = 1;


    }// end of while 


    // Close socket
    closesocket(in);

    file.close();
    WSACleanup();

    thread_write.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf)` doesn't do what you think it does. It should probably be `reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf)`. And `1450` should be `1450*sizeof(int)` because you have 1450 ints, and each int is more than one byte.

sendto needs a pointer to the data that it will send. If you pass it `&buf` (a pointer to `buf`) then you are sending the pointer `buf`. If you pass it `buf` (a pointer to the buffer) then you are sending the buffer.

---

When you build up an array of ints your computer stores them in memory as bytes like this: (maybe - it's platform-specific!)

```
Byte  0: 0 \
Byte  1: 0 |
Byte  2: 0 | int 0
Byte  3: 0 /
Byte  4: 1   \
Byte  5: 0   |
Byte  6: 0   | int 1
Byte  7: 0   /
Byte  8: 2     \
Byte  9: 0     |
Byte 10: 0     | int 2
Byte 11: 0     /
```

When the server treats these as bytes it will see the number 2 at index 8, and so on. If you want it to match, then perhaps the client should be creating an array of bytes (chars, same as the server) instead of ints.

Comment: I understand and applied it but it is not still working, should I make changes in server, about the size of char array array which is 1550

Comment: What is not working? Since your client is sending ints and your server is treating them as bytes, the memory layout will not be the same. Your 7 might be at index 28 or 31 or 56 or 63 when you read it as chars. Maybe you should make the client send chars as well?

Comment: but client is already sending chars with this `reinterpret_cast<char*>`